# How can I retrieve the last created Core Data parent entity along with its 1 to Many related entities in a @FetchRequest?

Tags: swiftui, core-location, nsfetchrequest, fetchrequest

In Core Data have 2 Entities - *LocationSet* and *Location* in a 1 to Many relationship
I want to Fetch all the Location children related to the last created LocationSet (using its property of .created date) to use in a View

My 2 FetchRequests work fine on their own but I would like to use the *LocationSet* returned in my first Fetch as a predicate for the 2nd fetch of the *Location* children

These are my FetchRequests for each entity,

```
@FetchRequest(entity: LocationSet.entity()
 ,sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \LocationSet.created, ascending: true)]
 )var fetchedLocSets: FetchedResults<LocationSet>

@FetchRequest(entity: Location.entity()
 ,sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Location.name, ascending: true)]
 )var fetchedLocations: FetchedResults<Location>
```

I have tried doing this in an init() but its not working and seems overly complicated so thinking this must have a more elegant solution?

I tried using init() to do the LocationSet fetch first to then use in the Location fetch but didn't work and also get the purple error
`Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.`

```
init(){
  let requestSets: NSFetchRequest<LocationSet> = LocationSet.fetchRequest()
  requestSets.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \LocationSet.name, ascending: true)]
  let fetchLS = FetchRequest<LocationSet>(fetchRequest: requestSets)
       
  if let locset = fetchLS.wrappedValue.first {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Location> = Location.fetchRequest()
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Location.name, ascending: true)]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "set_ofLocations == %@", locset)
    _fetchedLocations = FetchRequest<Location>(fetchRequest: request)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by another approach - essentially flipped the query. I used a predicate to retrieve all Locations limited by a give LocationSet id.

```
let uuidPred = NSPredicate(format:  "locationset.uuid_ == %@", UUID(uuidString: lastUUID.rawValue)! as CVarArg)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have pretty much given up on `@FetchRequest` inside of my `View`s because it is so limited in functionality compared to CoreData at large.

What I normally do is:

- Create a manager-object for accessing my `CoreData` model (My data managers are `@globalActor`s to more easily facilitate background fetches but this is not necessary and might complicate things for you if you are not 100% comfortable with merging contexts from different threads.)
- in `onAppear` I fetch my data inside a `Task` using my manager and once retrieved I update a `@State` property on the view with the fetched data (using `MainActor.run` to avoid more purple errors when fetching from a background context)